# How To Make Live Currency Conversion In Amazon Quicksight?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I need one filter where I can select different country based on this my table amount value can live conversion

how can archive this on amazon Quicksight

I tried and find in calculated filed and visual and filter but not getting any solution